# add a field in array in firebase without removing other fields in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a new field in a array but when i try to add a new field it will remove rest and add only the remaining one.
i tried this but not working

```
 collectionRef
        .doc("userIdLalit")
        .collection("stories")
        .doc("BHUCC3ewEeByJ6U68ygJ")
        .update(
      {
        "reactionModel": {
          "user": [
            {"fourth element": "Sam"},
          ],
        }
      },
    );
```

This code will remove the 0th and 1st element and add the fourth element but i want all of them whenever i add a new field

I tried with set method with merge true but didnt work

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FieldValue.arrayUnion()` to push a new item to the array:

```dart
collectionRef
  .doc("userIdLalit")
  .collection("stories")
  .doc("BHUCC3ewEeByJ6U68ygJ")
  .update({
    "reactionModel.user":  FieldValue.arrayUnion({"fourth element": "Sam"})
  });
```

Also the array is nested in a map so you would have to use dot notation to update it i.e. `"reactionModel.user"`.